# Create a Model Scope using hash attribute

Tags: ruby, model, mongoid

I am using [mongoid-history](https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history) gem and mongoid in Ruby. I am actually linking the mongo history to a model called SocialPost, so i can make something like.

```
history = current_user.social_posts.history_tracks
```

Now i need to filter this 'history' with a scope or a method that filter attribute 'association_chain' from history tracker model, but 'history_tracks' attributes are made in this way:

```
<HistoryTracker _id: 57bdc1cb65e59325ae000001, created_at: 2016-08-24 15:48:27 UTC, updated_at: 2016-08-24 15:48:27 UTC, association_chain: [{"name"=>"SocialPost", "id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57ac8b0f65e5930944000000')}], modified: {"facebook_likes_count"=>2594213, "tweeter_followers_count"=>0}, original: {}, version: 1, action: "update", scope: "social_post", modifier_id: nil>
```

So, how i can create a search in my HistoryTracker model that allow me to search a specific group of ids inside association_chain, something like this:

```
HistoryTracker.where(:association_chain.in => {"name"=>"SocialPost", "id"=>[GROUPS OF IDS TO SEARCH]}
```

**UPDATE using $elemMatch**

```
#test case multiple social_id: empty result
HistoryTracker.any_in({:association_chain.elem_match => [{name: 'SocialPost', :id.in => social_ids}] })

#test case 1 social_id: match result
HistoryTracker.any_in({:association_chain.elem_match => [{name: 'SocialPost', :id => social_ids.first}] })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found already a posible solution. The elemMatch should be constructed grouped with ids you need to collect, so this is what i did:

```
social_ids = [BSON::ObjectId('...1'), BSON::ObjectId('...2'), BSON::ObjectId('...3')]

#reorder the ids with the extra hash elements
a = []
social_ids.each do |id_bson|
  a << {name: 'SocialPost', id: id_bson}
end
```

And now you create the **'QUERY'**

```
HistoryTracker.any_in({:association_chain.elem_match => a})
```